# How do you stage selected lines with Git in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: git, aptana

I've got Aptana working nicely with Git, but there's only one thing that keeps me opening Git GUI:  Staging only part of a file.

In Git GUI, I can select some lines and either stage those lines, or stage the hunk they're in. In Aptana, it only seems to allow me to stage **all edits** to a file.

[image: Screenshot of Aptana Studio 3 Git commit dialog].

Does anybody know how to stage part of a file with Git in Aptana Studio 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is currently not implemented yet.  Please file a ticket at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD.

Thanks.